# Generator of a particular Z Module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I didn't find any similar questions.
Consider
$$M= \mathbb{Z}/d_1\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/d_2\mathbb{Z}\times \cdots \times \mathbb{Z}/d_n \mathbb{Z}$$
where $1<d_1|d_2|...|d_n$

How do I prove that every generator of M (i.e. a set $A \subset M$ such that $\forall m \in M :\exists a_1,..., a_n \in A$, $r_1,...,r_n \in \mathbb{Z}:m=\sum_{i=1}^{n}r_ia_i $) consists of at least $n$ elements?

I didn't get much far. I noticed that if we write a generic $a_i=(a_i^\left(1\right),...,a_i^\left(n\right))$, then: 
$| \langle a_i \rangle|=d_n \iff gcd(a_i^\left(n\right),d_n)=1$. Not sure if this is of any help. 
I also tried several numerical examples but I'm still stuck. I think the idea is to use induction.

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: In the decomposition you wrote down $d_1, \dots, d_n$ are unique. If $M$ had $<d$ generators, then you can build such a decomposition with $<d$ factors, which would give a contradiction to uniqueness.

Comment: @JulianQuast thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I don't see how one could then build such a decomposition with $<n$ factors. Also it is weird that you don't seem to use that each $d_i$ divides $d_{i+1}$..

Comment: That $d_i | d_{i+1}$ is used to prove uniqueness of this decomposition. You can read about it under "Structure theorem of finitely generated Z-modules" or "Smith normal form". If you understand the structure theorem, then you know how to construct such a decomposition with $<n$ factors. A way to get it is to use $R/a \oplus R/b \cong R/gcd(a,b) \oplus R/lcm(a,b)$ several times.